# How to Override msgbox Button to Unload Userform in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, overriding, userform, msgbox

I'm very new with vba excel. I'm trying to develop little tool for report formatting tasks in vba excel. I know if i put below code into a button, it will unload my form but how can i override a msgbox's button to unload whole userform?

```
Unload UserForm1
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean. Do you mean that you want to close a userform by clicking on a button on it?

Comment: Yes. I want my program to be closed entirely when user clicked on the button of msgbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (and as with Chris I'm not sure that I do), you do know that a msgbox can return a value and you can use that value to close your form? For example, the first one returns a value, the second doesn't:

```
Dim l As Long

l = MsgBox("What do you want to do?", vbOKCancel)

If l = vbCancel Then
     Unload UserForm1
Else
    MsgBox "You selected 'OK'"
End If
```

You can use the return value (l) to tell the code that called the msgbox to unload the form.

Comment: Hi Alan. Thanks for reply. When i try , it gives a msgbox with two buttons. (OK and Cancel) When i click on OK button, it doesn't unload the form, it falls to Else statement in the code. But when i click on Cancel button, it works. :S

Comment: Yes, if you read the code above that's what it's intended to do. I gave you that illustration to explain how the message box can have different buttons (depending on the argument that you pass it; in this case vbOkCancel) and that each button returns a different value (in this case either vbCancel or vbOK). You can then use an If block as I've done here to choose what action to take depending on which button the user clicks. If you want only one button make the argument vbOKOnly, though in that case you have no need of an If statement; just unload the form on the next line after the msgbox.

Comment: Ok Then. I used `vbOKOnly` and in both `If` and `Else` statements i wrote `Unload UserForm1`. That solves my problem :)

Before asking I already guessed MsgBox could be overrided like java's swing - JOptionPane but didn't know how, so i thought it would be a question for here. thanks for your helping